# Routing on a named route only

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have a `user-profile` routing module that looks like this:

```
const userProfileRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':id/view',
    component: UserProfileViewComponent,
    resolve: { 
      user: UrlUserResolverService,
      posts: PostsAllResolverService
    },
    canActivate: [ AccessGuard ],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'posts',
        outlet: 'tabs',
        component: TabPostsViewComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'followers',
        outlet: 'tabs',
        component: TabFollowersFollowingViewComponent,
        resolve: { followers: UserFollowersResolverService }
      },
      {
        path: 'following',
        outlet: 'tabs',
        component: TabFollowersFollowingViewComponent,
        resolve: { following: UserFollowingResolverService }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: ':id/notifications',
    component: UserProfileNotificationsComponent,
    resolve: { notifications: NotificationsResolverService },
    canActivate: [ AccessGuard ] 
  }
];
```

This all works fine when I'm on the mobile view of the app as navigating changes the url, as I'd expect.

But on tablet and above the `user-profile-view` appears in the sidebar, like so:

```
<div id="sidebar">
  <user-profile-view></user-profile-view>
</div>
```

So because the `user-profile` is in the sidebar I don't want the entire url to change - I only want the named router (tabs) to change but I can't figure out what to place in the `navigate` function.

Here's what I have so far, which works well for mobile:

```
goToChildRoute(route: string) {
  let queryParams = route === 'posts' ? { queryParams: null } : { queryParams: { id: this.user.pk } };
  this.router.navigate([`/user-profile/${this.user.pk}/view`, { outlets: { tabs: [route] } }], queryParams);
}
```

And the relevant html:

```
  <div class="tabs">
    <div *ngFor="let tab of tabs;" [id]="tab.route" class="tab" (click)="goToChildRoute(tab.route)">
      <p>{{ tab.count }}</p>
      <p>{{ tab.title }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <router-outlet name="tabs"></router-outlet>
```

So to reiterate - how do I change only the named router of `tabs` when I'm on tablet (768px) and above?

Comment: Is this problem active? Have you had the change to check out any of the answers maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i got the question, but probably you can do something like that:

```
<div *ngFor="let tab of tabs;" [id]="getTabRoute(tab)" class="tab" (click)="onTabClick(tab)">
  <p>{{ tab.count }}</p>
  <p>{{ tab.title }}</p>
</div>
```

```
onTabClick(tab: Tab) {
  const route = this.getTabRoute(tab);

  let queryParams = route === 'posts' ? { queryParams: null } : { queryParams: { id: this.user.pk } };
  this.router.navigate([`/user-profile/${this.user.pk}/view`, { outlets: { tabs: [route] } }], queryParams);
}

getTabRoute(tab: Tab) {
  return window.screen.width > 768 ? tab.tabletRoute : tab.mobileRoute;
}
```

Of course you need to modify your array of tabs so every tab would contain separate route for tablet and for mobile.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you asking, but generally, it's much clearer if you use [relative URL navigation](https://angular.io/guide/router#relative-navigation) in these cases.

> The router supports directory-like syntax in a link parameters list to
>   help guide route name lookup:
>
> ./ or no leading slash is relative to the current level.
>
> ../ to go up one level in the route path.
>
> You can combine relative navigation syntax with an ancestor path. If
>   you must navigate to a sibling route, you could use the ../
>   convention to go up one level, then over and down the sibling route
>   path.
>
> To navigate a relative path with the Router.navigate method, you must
>   supply the ActivatedRoute to give the router knowledge of where you
>   are in the current route tree.
>
> After the link parameters array, add an object with a relativeTo
>   property set to the ActivatedRoute. The router then calculates the
>   target URL based on the active route's location.

So something like this:

```
  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
              private router: Router,
              private location: Location) {
  }
```

and in the menu activation handler to  clear the last route

```
  const url = this
    .router
    .createUrlTree(['../'], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute})
    .toString();

  this.location.go(url);
```

to go to a new sub-route on the same level:

```
  const url = this
    .router
    .createUrlTree(['../', 'something-new-route'], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute})
    .toString();

  this.location.go(url);
```

The 'something-new-route' can be a variable (or URL parameter) as well.